# How do I in java add a stacktrace to my debugging printout

Tags: java, debugging

What's the easiest way to print a stacktrace from a debugging printout? Often during testing you would like to know the callstack leading up to the situation provoking a debug message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Thread.dumpStack();](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack())

Comment: The downside is that dumpStack() only goes to stderr, and you can't send it somewhere else like you can with an exception or Thread.getStackTrace().

Comment: Use logging.  Printing to stdout/stderr should only be done by OS utilities and "Hello World" apps.

Answer (score 20):

If you're using log4j

```
Exception e = new Exception();
log.error("error here", e);
```

will print the stacktrace to your log.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to save the stack trace into a String you can do this;

```
String exception = "";
for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace())
   exception += element.toString() + "\n";
```

Where e is, obviously, an exception.

Besides, it sounds very weird to autogenerate an own Exception just to find get a stack trace for a debug. Get Eclipse and use it's debug mode, it's really awesome.

Comment: Shouldn't one also step or recurse through e.getCause(), and get stack traces for all of those too?

Comment: I don't believe there IS a cause when you do it like this.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for multiple concatenations.

Answer (score 4):

Just creating an arbitrary exception does the trick for me:

```
System.out.println("Oops, the bad thing happened");
new IllegalStateException().printStackTrace();
```

Comment: I believe that this method will cause a warning in some IDEs, such as IntelliJ, because you're creating an exception but not throwing it.

I recommend the Thread.getStackTrace() method which has the same logic but it's hidden from the developer.

Comment: Thread.dumpStack() is easier if you just want to send it to stderr (saves having to loop over the stack trace elements yourself).

Comment: This method is useful in JavaME which doesn't have getStackTrace or dumpStack methods on Thread.

Answer (score 3):

As well as what @jjnguy said, if you don't have an exception, you can also call Thread.getStackTrace().

Answer (score 2):

You should be catching the exception in a try-catch block.

```
e.getStackTrace();
```

That returns StackTraceElement[] that you can then interpret.

Also:

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

will...print the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

To simply print the current stack trace to stderr, you can call:

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

which itself just calls:

```
new Exception("Stack trace").printStackTrace();
```

To output to **stdout** rather than stderr, pass `System.out` to `printStackTrace()`:

```
new Exception("Stack trace").printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because I needed it myself:

As inspired by answer [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection) , you can retrieve the call stack using

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Then you process and print/log whatever you are interested in. More work than using `Thread.dumpStack()`, but more flexible.