# JUnit: @Before only for some test methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have some common set up code that I've factored out to a method marked with `@Before`. However, it is not necessary for all this code to run for every single test. Is there a way to mark it so the `@Before` method only runs before certain tests?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just move out the tests that don't need the setup code into a separate test class. If you have some other code common to the tests that would be helpful to keep, move that out into a helper class.

Comment: real helpful @Kirschstein  :(  - "do it right in the first place"

Comment: This isn't an answer, to be honest. I'm in a situation where I really shouldn't move the test to another class, but I'd like to avoid executing the @BeforeMethod before one out of several dozen tests.

Answer (score 50):

## @Nested + @BeforeEach

Totally agree with the point of moving the related code to an inner class. So here what I have done.

1. Create an inner class inside your test class
2. Annotate the inner class with `@Nested`
3. Move all the test methods you want to use in the inner class
4. Write the init code inside the inner class and annotate it with `@BeforeEach`

Here is the code:

```
class Testing {

    @Test
    public void testextmethod1() {
    
      System.out.println("test ext method 1");
    
    }
    
    @Nested
    class TestNest{
    
       @BeforeEach
       public void init() {
          System.out.println("Init");
       }
    
       @Test
       public void testmethod1() {
          System.out.println("This is method 1");
       }
    
       @Test
       public void testmethod2() {
          System.out.println("This is method 2");
       }
    
       @Test
       public void testmethod3() {
          System.out.println("This is method 3");
       }
        
     }

     @Test
     public void testextmethod2() {
    
         System.out.println("test ext method 2");
    
     }

}
```

Here is the output

```
test ext method 1
test ext method 2
Init
This is method 1
Init
This is method 2
Init
This is method 3
```

Note: I am not sure if this is supported in Junit4. I am doing this in JUnit5

Comment: Did u mean `@BeforeEach` instead of `@ForEach` ?

Comment: Thanks, @DevanshSharma for pointing it out.  Corrected the typo.

Comment: I think there is still one `@ForEach` left in the answer, that could be improved. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @misteeque corrected the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to achieve also via [Assume](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assume.html) from JUnit. And then you can check the method name for which you want to process `@Before`.

```
public class MyTest {
     @Rule
     public TestName testName = new TestName();

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
       assumeTrue(testName.getMethodName().equals("myMethodName"));
       // setup follows
     }
}
```

Check the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4) for more insights about `@Rule`.

Comment: Don't use assume, it stops the whole test from running, not just the @Before method.   if(!testName.getMethodName().equals("myMethodName")) {return;} (excuse the spacing) would work better.

Comment: I frankly find the "if-test-name-equals" idea pointless, as you might as well just call the before and after function directly in the tests that need them, and eliminate the Before and After annotations.

Comment: @aliteralmind "... as you might as well just call the before and after function directly in the tests that need them..." - No, you can't! Sometimes, special annotations prevent from doing so. For example, @ Transactional annotation, which covers a @ Test method with a transaction implicitly. And, if you need to test concurrent behavior, you have to open another transaction somewhere outside the @ Test method!

Answer (score 3):

Now that it's 2023, I'd recommend sticking with JUnit 5.x

I'd also say that this is probably a micro-optimization.  I would not go to the effort until I measured my test time and saw that running the code when it wasn't necessary added a significant amount of time.

Comment: could you provide some more clarification?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about @Before, but I recently came up with a strategy for @After block to run selectively. The implementation was straight forward. I have some flags set to default values as part of the test class. They are reset to default values in @Before class. In the class I need to do things specific to a flag, I set those flags & in @After I check for flag values to do the respective jobs.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4.12 provide Enclosed Runner like

```java
@RunWith(Enclosed.class) 
public class GlobalTest{

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class InnerTest{
    
    }

}
```