# Apply a JUnit Custom @Rule a particular test method

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit-rule

Can I run a custom rule only for a particular test method in a test class?

```
public class TestClassExample
{
    @Rule
    public CustomRuleForOneEqualsOne customRuleForOneEqualsOne = new CustomRuleForOneEqualsOne();

    @Test
    public void test_OneEqualsOne()
    {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_TwoEqualsTwo()
    {
        assertEquals(2, 2);
    }
}
```

In the above test class can I use my `customRuleForOneEqualsOne` rule be used only for test method `test_OneEqualsOne` and not for `test_TwoEqualsTwo`.

I've seen other solutions on Stack Overflow:

1. Move the two test methods into different class [say this option is not possible for particulr scenario] (or)
2. [JUnit: @Before only for some test methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548462/junit-before-only-for-some-test-methods) as described by this post

I can somehow use the test method name and skip over the execution of the rule
but a drawback of this approach would be, each time I use the rule in a specific class for a specific set of methods, I need to add all those method names to a list to see if they are found, to determine the execution of the rest of the logic.

Is there any way to use a custom rule in a test class for a particular set of test methods while ignoring them for the other test methods in the same test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best of my knowledge, `@Rule` applies to all tests. Therefore, if you need `@Rule` to be used in a single `@Test` method only, don't use `@Rule`. In that case, your code would look like this:

```
public class TestClassExample {

    @Test
    public void test_OneEqualsOne() {
        CustomRuleForOneEqualsOne customRuleForOneEqualsOne = new CustomRuleForOneEqualsOne();
        // use customRuleForOneEqualsOne
    }

    @Test
    public void test_TwoEqualsTwo() {
        assertEquals(2, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought so, i knew it works against the concept of @Rule, but just wanted to reach out to see if it was possible