# Is there a way, I can fetch the name of current test method running in testNG and use it in the name of screenshot if test fails( in different class)

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using Reflection Method Class,or also ITestResult Class result to fetch the name of the currently running test,

---

```
@AfterMethod
public String getTestMethodName(ITestResult result)
{
return result.getName();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve test name on TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596632/retrieve-test-name-on-testng)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a parameter of type `ITestResult` in your `@AfterMethod` and `TestNG` will inject it

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
  System.out.println("method name:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
}
```

***OR***

*If you want to get the method name before the test is executed you can use the following:*

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@BeforeMethod
public void nameBefore(Method method)
{
    System.out.println("Test name: " + method.getName());       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating a new object, pass the testcase name to the constructor and initilaize a testcaseName variable with the value from the Test method.
LoginTest.java:

```
 public class LoginTest{
@Test
    public void sampleTest(Method method) {
        String testcaseName = method.getName();
        LoginPageActions loginPageActions = new LoginPageActions(testcaseName);
    }

}
```

LoginPageActions.java:

```
 public class LoginPageActions{
    private String testCaseName = null;
public LoginPageActions(String testcaseName) {
        this.testCaseName = testcaseName;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).