# junit append file to report

Tags: java, junit, surefire

I have a test written in JUnit. On fail I would like to append a file to the report.

My thoughts: I just have to get the path and report name, so I can put a custom file right next to it, so it can be easily found.

How do I get that report file or path name?

Additional information: Those tests are run via Eclipse or Jenkins.

**Update:**
the name can be found like this: [Get name of currently executing test in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4)

The path seems to be a surefire topic ...

Comment: I'm assuming that your test written in JUnit is not a unit test because I can't think of a reason why you'd ever want to do this in a unit test. Are you trying to report a file that you're reading/writing in an integration test?

Comment: you are right, its not a simple JUnit unit test but a test written in JUnit. I corrected my question that way.