# Why @Rule annotated fields in JUnit has to be public?

Tags: java, junit, public, junit-rule

In JUnit test case, a field annotated by `@Rule` must be public. It breaks a common Java coding convention (all class member variables should not be public). Why does JUnit require this?

Documentation for `@Rule`: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Rule.java

Answer (score 33):

The JUnit runner will need to access the field reflectively to run the rule. If the field was private the access would throw `IllegalAccessException`.

Another option would have been to have the runner modify the access from private to public before running the rule. However that could cause problems in case a security manager is enabled.

If you want to avoid having public fields in your test class you can from JUnit 4.11 annotate methods that return a `Rule` with `@Rule` or `@ClassRule`.

Comment: +1 You can also annotate a method with @Rule, so this would avoid the problem. You should add this to your answer.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I did not know that. Apparently new functionality in 4.11.

Comment: @KErlandsson - are You completely sure about that? This is what the JUnit API documentation states: "A field must be public, not static, and a subtype of TestRule (preferred) or MethodRule"

Comment: @dziki What do you refer to? Am I sure about what exactly?