# Junit @Rule and Maven Checkstyle Plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, checkstyle

Junit [@Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) and [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) seem to be at odds with each other.

If a `@Rule` is `private` or package-private then the result is:

```
java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'someRule' must be public.
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.addError
```

However if `@Rule` is made `public` the checkstyle will complain:

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:checkstyle (checkstyle-test) @ web-edge-server ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
SomeTest.java: Variable 'someRule' must be private and have accessor methods.
```

So two questions:

1. If I'd like to continue to use the `@Rule` annotation what is there a way to suppress this warning locally, or within tests, without disabling the checkstyle rule globally.
2. Does anyone know why junit requires `@Rule` to be public?  This seems unnecessary as it could be made accessible using reflection in any case.

Edit: Item 2 is specifically covered by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335558/why-rule-annotated-fields-in-junit-has-to-be-public).

Comment: For 2/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335558/why-rule-annotated-fields-in-junit-has-to-be-public

Comment: For 1/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code (I use this one for the close as duplicate vote)

Comment: What Checkstyle version do you use?

Comment: @MichalKordas maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15

Comment: @RC while 2 is explicitly answered, in the case of 1, the article provided is quite general.  Still not seeing specifically which `@SuppressWarning` will allow for using `@Rule`.

Comment: Question should be reopened. It has solution: just update Plugin to 2.17 and violation will be gone.

Comment: @MichalKordas upgrading from 2.15=>2.17 does indeed fix the issue.  Do you know what the name of the rule is in 2.15 for the purpose of suppression providing that would be the best of both worlds.  I can change the question a bit and reopen.

Comment: the name should be "checkstyle:visibilitymodifier" http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#VisibilityModifier

Comment: @vpiTriumph it's VisibilityModifier check, your problem was just a bug that was recently fixed

Comment: @MichalKordas you should add that as an answer (when reopened)

Comment: @RC but question is closed and I can't

Comment: Using `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:visibilitymodifier")` actually doesn't do the job for the assignment or on the class.  Upgrading to 2.17 does indeed suppress the warning.  Also, I voted to reopen, may need @RC to cast a final to get the question reopened.

Comment: I already voted to reopen (NB: you closed it not me..) and you need 5 votes for a reopen. For the suppresswarning, you need to use the checkstyle one and to enable the annotation in the config.

Comment: @vpiTriumph is my answer fine for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Checkstyle 6.5 [`VisibilityModifier`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#VisibilityModifier) check gained new property `ignoreAnnotationCanonicalNames` which is by default set to `org.junit.Rule`, so `@Rule` fields should not trigger violations in this check.

According to [release history page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/history.html), Checkstyle Maven Plugin 2.15 uses Checkstyle 6.1.1 underneath, so it's enough to **update plugin to 2.17** to have the fix.

Answer (score 2):

In your checkstyle xml you can specify the [suppression filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#XML_Structure) as follows:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
  <property name="file" value="${samedir}/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

And then you can explicitly exclude that check from tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
        <suppress checks="VisibilityModifier" files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\]" /> 
</suppressions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that can be used to solve this issue *without* upgrading to version 2.17 of the plugin is to simply use comments to toggle the checkstyle on and off:

```
//CHECKSTYLE:OFF
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
//CHECKSTYLE:ON
```