# JUnit Rule and cdi

Tags: java, cdi, unboundid-ldap-sdk, junit-rule

I'm not really familiar with cdi or or JUnit Rule (in fact I've just discovered them) but I try to test my ldap api with the [embedded-ldap-junit](https://github.com/zapodot/embedded-ldap-junit) library (based on [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java)) following [this post](http://www.hascode.com/2016/07/ldap-testing-with-java-apacheds-vs-embedded-ldap-junit/). I precise that my api is not based on UnboundId LDAP SDK !

Here is my code :

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class LdapTest extends TestCase {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LdapTest.class);
    public static final String DOMAIN_DSN = "dc=my.domain";
    public static final String LDIF_FILE = "agents.ldif";
    public static final String BPM_SCHEMA = "schema.ldif";

    @Inject
    private LDAPManager ldapManager;

    @Rule
    public EmbeddedLdapRule embeddedLdapRule = EmbeddedLdapRuleBuilder.newInstance().usingDomainDsn(DOMAIN_DSN)
        .importingLdifs(LDIF_FILE).withSchema(BPM_SCHEMA).build();

    @Test
    public void getAgent() throws Exception {
        embeddedLdapRule.ldapConnection();
        DirContext dirContext = embeddedLdapRule.dirContext();
        ldapManager.setContext(dirContext);
        assertNotNull(ldapManager.getAgent("123"));
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I have the following Exception :

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075 Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  public@RunWith @ApplicationScoped class org.mycompany.LdapTest
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkBeanImplementation(ManagedBean.java:459)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.initialize(AbstractClassBean.java:176)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initialize(ManagedBean.java:329)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:117)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:217)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:357)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.ForwardingBootstrap.deployBeans(ForwardingBootstrap.java:70)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:135)
at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.createTest(CdiRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.methodBlock(CdiRunner.java:122)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

---

I tried to play on the embeddedLdapRule access level modifiers (private,/ protected / public) with no success. Could you please explain to me what I do wrong ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found an answer : [CdiUnit test with Junit @Rule is impossible because of a public private field paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40176003/2145671)

So the solution is :

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class LdapTest extends TestCase {
    public static final Logger LOGGER =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(LdapTest.class);
    public static final String DOMAIN_DSN = "dc=my.domain";
    public static final String LDIF_FILE = "agents.ldif";
    public static final String BPM_SCHEMA = "schema.ldif";

    @Inject
    private LDAPManager ldapManager;

    private EmbeddedLdapRule embeddedLdapRule = EmbeddedLdapRuleBuilder.newInstance()
        .usingDomainDsn(DOMAIN_DSN)
        .importingLdifs(LDIF_FILE)
        .withSchema(BPM_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    @Rule
    public EmbeddedLdapRule getLdapRule() {
        return embeddedLdapRule;
    }

    @Test
    public void getAgent() throws Exception {
        embeddedLdapRule.ldapConnection();
        DirContext dirContext = embeddedLdapRule.dirContext();
        ldapManager.setContext(dirContext);
        assertNotNull(ldapManager.getAgent("123"));
    }
}
```