# Get the name of currently executing @Test method in @Before in JUNIT

Tags: java, junit

I want to get the name of currently executing TestCase Method in @Before method.
Example

```
public class SampleTest()
{
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        //get name of method here
    }

    @Test
    public void exampleTest()
    {
        //Some code here.
    }
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4 ?

Comment: add a field `previousName` in your test class and set its value at the end of each test method with After

Answer (score 22):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4), try using @Rule and TestName combination.

As per the [documentation](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/Rule.html) before method should have test name.

> Annotates fields that contain rules. Such a field must be public, not
>   static, and a subtype of TestRule. The Statement passed to the
>   TestRule will run any Before methods, then the Test method, and
>   finally any After methods, throwing an exception if any of these fail

Here is the test case using Junit 4.9

```
public class JUnitTest {

    @Rule public TestName testName = new TestName();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println(testName.getMethodName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test ...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `@Rule` annotation with `org.junit.rules.TestName` class

```
@Rule public TestName name = new TestName();

@Test 
public void test() {
    assertEquals("test", name.getMethodName());
}
```