# Get currently executing @Test method in @Before in JUnit 4

Tags: java, junit4

I want to get currently executing test method in `@Before` so that I can get the annotation applied on currently executing method.

```
public class TestCaseExample {
       @Before
       public void setUp() {
           // get current method here.
       }

       @Test
       @MyAnnotation("id")
       public void someTest {
           // code
       }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4 for some more discussion about this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try TestName rule

```
public class TestCaseExample {
  @Rule
  public TestName testName = new TestName();

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Method m = TestCaseExample.class.getMethod(testName.getMethodName());       
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Comment: This code gives name of currently executing method and with name of method we can't get annotation applied to it. So I want actual method and then I want to call method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)

Comment: If you have the method name you can use reflections to get the actual method.

Comment: Even better, you can write your own version of `TestName` which grabs the annotation, rather than the name.

Comment: Thanks Evgenity Dorofeev and Andre. I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Evgeniy pointed to the `TestName` rule (which i'd never heard of - thanks, Evgeniy!). Rather than using it, i suggest taking it as a model for your own rule which will capture the annotation of interest:

```
public class TestAnnotation extends TestWatcher {
    public MyAnnotation annotation;

    @Override
    protected void starting(Description d) {
        annotation = d.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    }
}
```