# jUnit4.0 : how to know current test method name?

Tags: java, junit

I've implemented a feature in my jUnit tests that takes, for every test case, a fresh copy of a data source. This copy is taken in a folder specific for each test case. The idea is that every test case can start from a clean situation, manipulate it and let it as such after the run. This is often useful when the test fails for analysing the problem.

For now I have to call this feature directly in the test method because I don't know how to retrieve the current test name:

```
public void testTest1() {
   TestHelper th=TestHelper.create("testTest1",subPathToDataSource);
   // do the test...
   Path dataPath = th.getDataPath();
   ...
   }
```

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
Path dataPath;

@Before
public initTest() {
   th=TestHelper.create(SomeJUnitObject.getCurrentTestName(),subPathToDataSource);
   ...
   }

public void testTest1() {
   // do the test...
   Path dataPath = th.getDataPath();
   ...
   }
```

Until now I found as answers : "You don't need to know that"... But I do need it !
Is this possible ?

Kind regards

Comment: Get a stack trace and your method will be at the top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Comment: Test classes are classes like any other; why don't you just create an abstract class and make your actual test classes inherit it?

Comment: This is available in Junit 4.7 with the TestName Rule.  Can you can use Junit 4.7+? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the TestName rule.

You should be able to add in your test class:

```
@Rule TestName name=new TestName();
```

And then access it.

(On phone, so can't check versions support/details - might be 4.x only)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach; create an abstract class which your "real" test classes inherit.

I have several such examples in my projects and here I will give one, mainly [testing for individual JSON Patch operations](https://github.com/fge/json-patch/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/fge/jsonpatch).

All my test files are JSON, and located under an appropriately named resource directory. The base, abstract class is [`JsonPatchOperationTest`](https://github.com/fge/json-patch/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/fge/jsonpatch/JsonPatchOperationTest.java). And here is the *full code* of `AddOperationTest` which tests for JSON Patch's add operation:

```
public final class AddOperationTest
    extends JsonPatchOperationTest
{
    public AddOperationTest()
        throws IOException
    {
        super("add");
    }
}
```

And that's it! Not even one test method in this class, but of course your implementation may vary.

In your case you probably want to pass the directory name as a constructor argument, or the like.