# Is there a correct way to have a util method to find test resource paths?

Tags: java, csv, path

I am writing a small test to read a CSV file (using testng).
I found some code to do just that and some other lines to find the resource folder itself.

Now as I am re-using this in other scenarios, I thought that I could just create a util method instead of copy pasting:

```
public static String prepFilepath(Class c) {

    URL url = c.getResource("");
    String location = url.getPath();

    String packageName = c.getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/");

    int l = location.lastIndexOf(packageName);
    return location.substring(0, l);
}
```

and it is called by my test like this:

```
@Test
public void testImport(){
    File testFile = new File(ImportUtils.prepFilepath(this.getClass()), inputFileName);
    //...
}
```

However I don't know if it is the correct way:

- Is it ok to pass a class reference as parameter? (I had never done that before for such a small purpose)
- Are there more elegant ways?
- Is it generic enough to justify the util?

**Edit:** 
I am using testng

Comment: Note that you can let JUnit give you the name of the test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4

Comment: Why don't you load the CSV stream from the classpath using Class.getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: Here is an old Javaworld article which describes how to load a properties file as a classpath resource; it applies to all types of files though: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same package as the class then we can get URL to the file this way

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);
```

if we need to get File from URL we can do it this way

```
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```