# Naming screenshot based on the method name in runtime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, jbehave

Could someone help me in the below situation?

I've to create a common method to get screenshots using Selenium Webdriver where the file name of the screenshot should get updated as the name of the method where I call it.

This is what I have now:

Created a method to get the Timestamp and use it to the file name:

```
public String getTimeStamp() {
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return timestamp;
}

//  Method to get the Screenshot at any given instance. The Screenshots taken are copied to Screenshots folder under `"build\jbehave\view"`.
public void getScreenShots() throws Exception {
    File srcfile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File folder = new File("Screenshots");

    if(folder.exists()){
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcfile, new File("./build/jbehave/view/Screenshots/" + "Screenshot_" + getTimeStamp() + ".png"));
    }else {

        File dir1 = new File("Screenshots");
        dir1.mkdir();
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcfile, new File("./build/jbehave/view/Screenshots/" + "Screenshot_" + getTimeStamp() + ".png"));

    }
    }
```

I'm looking for a method which can get the name of the methods where I call the above `getScreenShots()` method and have it as my file name in run time instead of having Timestamps.

Comment: Is this being used in a test? If yes do you mean the name of the test method?

Comment: Using JUnit that would be easy as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4)

Comment: @Gavin: I've edited my post to make it more clear. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @el_tomato: I'm using JBehave to write my code and run it as JUnit

Comment: @el_tomato has linked the right answer above. In junit you use the Testname rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can get method name from stack trace of current thread:

```
byte[] scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
String filename = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].toString();
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(filename), scrFile);
```

In this example, the `filename` is a method, which executes this fragment (it is 1 in stack trace).

Comment: I'm using the below method to get the screenshot: File srcfile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); I'm converting the file type to .png while copying to a specific path. Could you please tell me if it can be done in the method that you mentioned?

Comment: just use File.renameTo method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the updates. But renameTo method as mentioned in the link that you shared states that the rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another. Could you please add that code which can be used to copy the file (filename in this case) to a desired location?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4) to get the method of the running test.
And then use the selenium driver to get the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the method from `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, but there can be issues: [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29).

Comment: I'm just learning Selenium and JBehave now with little knowledge on Java. Could you please explain me what issues can prop up if we use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()?