# Print a pattern while executing test in java

Tags: java, printing, junit

Currently all our junit tests are following a convention using -

```
@Test
public void testXYZ() {
  System.out.println("--------------Testing XYZ-----------");
  // actual test logic goes here
  System.out.println("--------------Successfully tested XYZ-----------");
}

@Test
public void text123() {    
  System.out.println("--------------Testing 123-----------");
  // actual test logic goes here
  System.out.println("--------------Successfully tested 123-----------");
}
```

How can I get rid of these redundant print statements but still have them on display?

Comment: read about aspect oriented programming

Comment: do you mean besides using `@Before` and `@After` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473401/get-name-of-currently-executing-test-in-junit-4

Comment: @ochi - If they can help, not an issue, but how go i generalise the output

Comment: use `@Before` for `System.out.println("--------------Testing -----------");` and `@After` for `System.out.println("--------------Successfully tested -----------");`

Comment: @ajb - Its not about getting the name of the test, its about optimising the print block code.

Comment: @pahan mix that up with test names!!??

Comment: Just like @pahan said, create a method for the line printed at the beginning of the test and another method for the line printed at the end.  Annotate each accordingly.  It should be all you need. If you need to get the name of the test running, combine with @ ajb's proposed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of JUnit, you can [read the docs](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) for the `TestWatcher` class.

Below an adapted example from their page (**not tested**).

```
public static class WatchmanTest {
  private static String watchedLog;

  @Rule
  public TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
       String methodName = description.getMethodName();
       System.out.println("--------------Failed Test " + methodName + "-----------");   
    }

    @Override
    protected void starting(Description description) {
       String methodName = description.getMethodName();
       System.out.println("--------------Testing " + methodName + "-----------");   
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
       String methodName = description.getMethodName();
       System.out.println("--------------Successfully Tested " + methodName + "-----------");
    }
 };

  @Test
  public void fails() {
      fail();
  }

  @Test
  public void TestXYZ() {
      // actual test logic here
      // ...
  }

  @Test
  public void Test123() {
      // actual test logic here
      // ...
  }
```

}