# How to modify TestNG test method based upon the values passed to custom annotation?

Tags: java, testing, testng

In my TestNG based test cases . I have a test class with a test method  annotated with my custom annotation along with the @Test annotation .I want to change the behaviour of the test method based upon the parameters that are passer to my custom annotation . Is there a way to achieve this in TestNG ?

Comment: That depends on the behaviour you are wanting to change.  If you are passing a string to the test, simply using that string as a URL will change the behaviour of the test based on the parameters.  However, I don't think this is what you are talking about, and even if you were more specific, I don't think that it is possible.  Feel free to explain what behaviour you want changed though.

Comment: @MrTi Consider your case itself for URL , i want to achieve the same . Passing parameter in my custom annotation and using that value in my test .

Comment: Then this is what you are looking for: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805200/retrieve-java-annotation-attribute - Your custom annotation should have retentionpolicy as runtime