# How to make jxpath read @xmlelement name attribute instead of actual field name?

Tags: java, jxpath

I have a class with a field which looks like this

```
@XmlElement(name = "Name", namespace = "a:b:c:1", required = true)
protected String firstName
```

I want to use JXPath like this

```
String name = (String) context.getValue("Name");
```

But it doesn't recognize the XMLElement name attribute. Is there any way to make it do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you *can*. JXPath allows navigation of bean hierarchies using the standard bean get/is notation, but doesn't provide a means of accessing annotations on a field.

I think you should perhaps look at [this answer re. finding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805200/retrieve-java-annotation-attribute). Perhaps you can combine with a JXPath solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this as Brian suggested

```
Field[] fields = rq.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Map<String, String> annotationMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(Field field:fields)
    {

        if(field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class).name().equals("Name"))
        {
            annotationMap.put("Name", field.getName());
        }
    }

String name = (String) context.getValue(annotationMap.get("Name"));
    System.out.println(name);
```

But won't this approach be tedious if I have a 100 fields or more? Is there a better way to do this?