# jxpath not honoring JAXB's XmlElement name of xjc-generated classes

Tags: jaxb, jxpath

I use an XML Schema Definition and JAXB to generate Java classes with proper `@XmlElement` or `@XmlRootElement` annotations.

Since the schema has some deep nesting in it (not my choice), I'd rather use `jxpath` to access deeply buried classes using an XPath (rather than cumbersome daisy-chain of `.getThat()` and `that != null`).

The problem is that some of the XML element names contain dashes, e.g. `foo-bar`.  When I try to access elements using `org.apache.jxpath`, I need to rewrite my XPath so that such names are camel-cased instead (`fooBar`) like the name of the actual Java objects.  Is there any way to tell `jxpath` to find the elements using the XPath corresponding to the XML element names (instead of the camel-cased Bean names)?

I think it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947096/how-to-make-jxpath-read-xmlelement-name-attribute-instead-of-actual-field-name), however in my case I don't actually case what kind of tricks and decorations are used on the auto-generated classes, as long as xjc can do it.

Here is a simple example to illustrate the issue.

First, a small XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="record">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foo-bar" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Compile it...

```
xjc -p org.pd.jx example.xsd
```

Here is the xjc-generated `Record.java` class (minus comments):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"fooBar"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
public class Record {
    @XmlElement(name = "foo-bar", required = true)
    protected String fooBar;
    public String getFooBar() {return fooBar;}
    public void setFooBar(String value) {this.fooBar = value;}
}
```

Then, trying to access the data via `jxpath` (in practice I have to deal with lots of deeply nested classes), one can see below that the correct XPath (`"foo-bar"`) doesn't work, but a camel-cased version does.

```
    Record record = new Record();
    record.setFooBar("hello world");

    JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(record);
    context.setLenient(true);
    String a = (String)context.getValue("foo-bar", String.class);  // is null
    String b = (String)context.getValue("fooBar", String.class);  // "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe JXPath operates on an objects properties and not the XML elements they correspond to.  I do not believe that JXPath parses any of the JAXB metadata so it wouldn't know the XML nodea you have mapped.  What you are seeing appears to be the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @BlaiseDoughan. That's what I was fearing... Ah well. Since for these classes I am into convenience, I wrote a quick rewrite of the XPath to translate it into the class name based (i.e. camel-case) form.