# Get a Column Name from Class in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

this is not a homework or the actual code. It is a quick example created to explain the situation.

```
public student {
private long studentId;
Private long studentName;
@Column(name = "ID")
getStudentId(){
}

@Column(name = "NAME"
getStudentName(){
}

}
```

is there a way to have a dyanmic way to get the column name

```
 Criterion rest1 = Restrictions.eq("NAME", criteriaModel.getEncounterTypeClassCd());
```

dont want to hard code the column name is there a better way  that doing what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read the annotaton's value. Right?

Some thing like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805200/retrieve-java-annotation-attribute) thread might help.

Anyway defining the value in a constant and using it in both places would be simpler, as the column names don't change that often after the development phase.