# Spring @PreAuthorize SpEL content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there a way to programmatically get the SpEL contained in the @PreAuthorize annotation of a specified endpoint VERB+PATH?

Comment: Lots of ugly reflection probably. I'd try not to need this kind of deep dependency on framework internals. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Using reflexion ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805200/retrieve-java-annotation-attribute

Comment: @zapl I'm trying to find a way to have a full report of all the endpoints created and corresponding authorizations

Comment: Uh, ok, something like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/RequestMappingEndpoint.java is maybe a good start. Knows at least about paths verbs and methods   - produces the overview available at `/mappings` when you have a boot application with actuator enabled

Comment: thanks @zapl i'll check it