# How to get string name of a method in java?

Tags: java, reflection

How can I find out through reflection what is the string name of the method?

For example given:

```
class Car{
   public void getFoo(){
   }
}
```

I want to get the string "getFoo", something like the following:

```
 Car.getFoo.toString() == "getFoo" // TRUE
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since methods aren't objects themselves, they don't have direct properties (like you would expect with first-class functions in languages like JavaScript).

The closest you can do is call [`Car.class.getMethods()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods())

`Car.class` is a [`Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object which you can use to invoke any of the reflection methods.

However, as far as I know, a method is not able to identify itself.

Comment: with Java 9 or later we can now use a [`StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html) to find the actual class and method names (I know, 12 years *late*)

Answer (score 41):

You can get the String like this:

```
Car.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getName();
```

This is for the case of a single method in your class. If you want to iterate through all the declared methods, you'll have to iterate through the array returned by `Car.class.getDeclaredMethods()`:

```
for (Method method : Car.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    String name = method.getName();
}
```

You should use `getDeclaredMethods()` if you want to view all of them, `getMethods()` will return only *public* methods.

And finally, if you want to see the name of the method, which is executing at the moment, you should use this code:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
```

This will get a stack trace for the current thread and return the name of the method on its top.

Comment: Thanks, i'm afraid I don't really want to be tied down to the "one-method-per-class" thing...

Comment: You can get all of the methods of the class or just the method being executed at the moment. See my edits. :)

Comment: Thanks. Curious. But I do need a name of a method that is Not currently executing. It seems like java does not provide a way to do that...

Comment: I don't get it, you want to get the name of the method, but how are you gonna specify the method?

Comment: Hi , by doing Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName(); yo get the first method in the stack , which at that moment is "getStackTrace" ,you should do Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(); in order to get the one which have the code line, if you want to decouple this method so you dont have to duplicate it in each place i suggest to make it static in a class and call it with [2], i haven't tryed thought i seems logic for it to work.

Comment: instead of Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();, I had better luck with Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(); :) it should work everytime, although I haven't tried it in a constructor or lazy loading situation

Comment: On Android the method name is in the third element: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()

Comment: @GodfreyDuke Well, I outlined the general strategy, you have to experiment a little on the target platform. It may even be that different Android versions behave a bit differently.

Comment: Thanks, This one works perfect Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();

Answer (score 15):

So, you want to get the name of the currently executing method? Here's a somewhat ugly way to do that:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.fillInStackTrace();
String methodName = e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Comment: Actually, this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod() works just fine!

Comment: momomo, no, it doesn't.

class Test {    
    @Test
    public void testReflection() {
        assert (this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod() == null);
    }
}

Answer (score 10):

Look into this thread:

[Getting the name of the currently executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

It offers some more solutions - for example:

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8, you can do this with a few lines of code (almost) without any additional libraries. The key is to convert your method into a serialisable lambda expression. Therefore, you can just define a simple interface like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SerializableFunction<I, O> extends Function<I, O>, Serializable {
  // Combined interface for Function and Serializable
}
```

Now, we need to convert our lambda expression into a `SerializedLambda` object. Apparently, Oracle does not really want us to do that, so take this with a grain of salt... As the required method is private, we need to invoke it using reflections:

```
private static final <T> String nameOf(SerializableFunction<T, ?> lambda) {
  Method findMethod = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(lambda.getClass(), "writeReplace");
  findMethod.setAccessible(true);

  SerializedLambda invokeMethod = (SerializedLambda) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(findMethod, lambda);
  return invokeMethod.getImplMethodName();
}
```

I'm using Springs `ReflectionUtils` class here for simplicity, but you can of course replace this by manually looping through all superclasses and use `getDeclaredMethod` to find the `writeReplace` method.

And this is it already, now you can use it like this:

```
@Test
public void testNameOf() throws Throwable {
  assertEquals("getName", nameOf(MyClassTest::getName));
}
```

I haven't checked this with Java 9s module system, so as a little disclaimer it might be more tricky to do this with more recent Java versions...

Comment: When implementing "ReflectionUtils.findMethod" be sure to use "getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace")" or "getDeclaredMethods()" not "getMethod("writeReplace")" or "getMethods()"

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 import java.lang.reflect.*;
    public class DumpMethods {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(args[0]);
                Method m[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(m[i].toString());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, since you already know the method name, can't you just type it as a string?

Instead of (pseudo) `Class.methodName.toString()`, just use `"methodName`".

Otherwise you can use `Class#getDeclaredMethods()` to get all the methods in a class

Comment: I don't want to use a string. I may refactor my method name in the future.

Comment: IDEs have the ability to look into strings when refactoring