# How to print a Method name along with it's return value?

Tags: java, methods

I have FooClass with barMethod() that returns "bazz" string. How to print in console `barMethod` along with `bazz`?

For example:

```
public class FooClass {

    String barMethod() {
        return "baz"; 
    }
}
```

```
System.out.println(FooClass.barMethod()) //Prints "baz"
```

How can I print the following?

```
customPrint(FooClass.barMethod()) //barMethod = baz
```

Note: I can't modify barMethod() or FooClass.

Found [How to get a string name of method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023354/how-to-get-string-name-of-a-method-in-java) on stack overflow but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: How about just `System.out.println("barMethod = " + FooClass.barMethod());`?

Comment: I have 50 such methods, doing this manually is painful

Comment: Are all 50 methods part of `FooClass`?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, they're part of FooClass

Comment: are you sure the answer to the linked question does not work? basic idea: `for (var method : FooClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", method.getName(), method.invoke(null))`  ((assuming only `static` methods))

Answer (score 0):

```
Class yourClass = YourClass.class;
for (Method method : yourClass.getMethods()){
    // format the output as you wish using something like:  
    System.out.println(method.getName() + " " + method.invoke(obj, args));           
}
```

Comment: What if you don't have any args?

Comment: then, `args = null;` )

Comment: Maybe specify what `obj` is. Also, this particular algorithm assumes you want to call and print every single public method that the class has, rather than a select few. But it demonstrates the general idea!

Comment: Getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` with `args = null`

Comment: Without `args` also works, ie `method.invoke(obj)`. But still getting the same `IllegalArgumentException `

Comment: If you're copying this algorithm, you must keep in mind that it passes the arguments (or lack thereof) to all the methods, and very likely, the methods of the class don't all have the same number of parameters. I'm guessing that's the reason it fails - because of a mismatch in arguments and parameters.

Comment: Got it, there were certain functions which are implicitly part of the class, like `wait`, `equals` which accept a single param. Only for those I was getting the above exception.

Comment: There's another method that maaay be more useful to you than `getMethods()`, and that is `getDeclaredMethods()`. It returns all methods a class and its interfaces declare, but not the ones it merely inherits from its superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the reflection  API to call the method. For a brief introduction and examples, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection). Also, see aviad's answer.