# How to get annotations of interface or abstract class methods in Java

Tags: java

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IFoo{
@AnnotationTest(param="test")
String invoke();
}
```

and I implement this like this:

```
public class Foo implements IFoo{
@Override
public String invoke(){
  Method method = new Object() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
  AnnotationTest ann = method.getAnnotation(AnnotationTest.class);
  if(ann == null){
    System.out.printl("Parent method's annotation is unreachable...")
}

}

}
```

If it is possible to reach parent's annotation, I want to learn the way of it.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [java.lang.annotation.Inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) ?

Comment: @superbob doesn;t work for interfaces

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428858/annotation-is-not-inherited-from-interface-method

Answer (score 15):

You can use Spring [AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-) to read annotations from interfaces.

Example :

**Interface `I.java`**

```
public interface I {
    @SomeAnnotation
    void theMethod();
}
```

**Implementing class `A.java`**

```
public class A implements I {
    public void theMethod() {
        Method method = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
        SomeAnnotation ann = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, AnnotationTest.class);
    }
}
```

It obviously requires to include in your project (and import) Spring framework classes.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz, read the Javadoc for AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation.

Comment: Example added @ibrahimyilmaz, also consider getting the method as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139984/java-getting-the-currently-executing-method-corresponding-object#19773921), it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: I know how to use method:) I cant import spring core library into my android project. I added this my gradle conf. 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE'

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz, try to fix your gradle issue, if you can't ask the an appropriate question. Then see if your initial question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to get it. If you really need, you have to manually loop over `getInterfaces()` to find if any implemented interface has the annotation. If you want to search for (eventually abstract) superclasses and the annotation is not `@Inherited`, you can again iterate the superclass chain until finding `Object` (*).

But beware, as following post states, there are good reasons for this not to be directly implemented in Java : [Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

(*) If the annotation is `@Inherited` it is automatically searched on superclasses, but not on interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

you can't inherit annotations.

But a framework that uses an annotation can check to see if annotation is present on superclass

Comment: is it work for abstract class? if it is, I can convert interface to abstrack class