# Can a method figure out its own name using reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, methods

I know that you can use reflection in Java to get the name of class, methods, fields...etc at run time. 
I was wondering can a method figure out its own name while its inside it's self? Also, I don't want to pass the name of the method as a String parameter either.

For example

```
public void HelloMyNameIs() {
  String thisMethodNameIS = //Do something, so the variable equals the method name HelloMyNameIs. 
}
```

If it that is possible, I was thinking it would probably involve using reflection, but maybe it doesn't.

If anybody know, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not with reflection, no, answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
public String getCurrentMethodName()
{
     StackTraceElement stackTraceElements[] = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
     return stackTraceElements[1].toString();
}
```

inside the method you want to get the name of.

```
public void HelloMyNameIs()
{
    String thisMethodNameIS = getCurrentMethodName();
}
```

(Not reflection, but I don't think it is possible.)

Comment: There are performance implications with this technique, so use with caution.  But it's the best solution you're going to get.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Very true. And because of that, it really shouldn't be used in a release build, only for debugging purposes.

Comment: Great advice about performance and the ability to find out a method name inside of itself. I guess, I will steer clear of using this technique because it would effect the speed of the build.

Comment: Why not use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() instead of new Throwable?

Comment: @Andrejs: If you read the documentation, both retrieve the stack trace from the current thread.

Comment: But only one of them creates an extra Throwable object

Comment: Its possible to avoid this extra object creation, that's all

Answer (score 6):

This one-liner works using reflection:

```
public void HelloMyNameIs() {
  String thisMethodNameIS = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
}
```

The downside is that the code can't be moved to a separate method.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Proxy all your methods (that override a method defined in an interface) can know their own names.

```
import java . lang . reflect . * ;

interface MyInterface
{
      void myfun ( ) ;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
      public void myfun ( ) { /* implementation */ }
}

class Main
{
      public static void main ( String [ ] args )
      {
            MyInterface m1 = new MyClass ( ) ;
            MyInterface m2 = ( MyInterface ) ( Proxy . newProxyInstance (
                  MyInterface . class() . getClassLoader ( ) ,
                  { MyInterface . class } ,
                  new InvocationHandler ( )
                  {
                        public Object invokeMethod ( Object proxy , Method method , Object [ ] args ) throws Throwable
                        {
                             System . out . println ( "Hello.  I am the method " + method . getName ( ) ) ;
                             method . invoke ( m1 , args ) ;
                        }
                  }
            ) ) ;
            m2 . fun ( ) ;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack trace from current thread also:

```
public void aMethod() {  
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()); 
}
```