# Get the name of the current method being executed

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Well what I am basically doing is an app which has many activities. I have a few friends with android phones and I gave them the app for testing. However, it sometimes goes into endless cycles and does strange behaviour which I am not able to understand due to their lack of programming experience and inability to dump the logcat in those particular moments.

So what I need to do is to create a static always visible window, probably popup window, that shows in which method is the program now.

So my question would be, which is the best way to achieve this functionality and how to retrieve the current method the App is in (it has several threads).

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: Can Android do thread dumps?  This might turn out to be a very useful debugging tool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
public String getCurrentMethod(){
    try{
        throw new Exception("");
    }catch(Exception e){
        return e.getStackTrace()[0].toString();
    }
    return ""; // This never happens
}
```

It will return something like this:
 `ClassName.methodName():123`

Comment: Note: you don't need to *throw* an `Exception` to get it's stacktrace: `new Exception().getStackTrace()[0]` should work just fine.

Comment: Of course. That's what I get for coding without compiling :)

Answer (score 6):

There are many answers for this if you search SO. This is a simple method

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

You should refer this post.
[Getting the name of the current executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method-java)

Comment: Note that each use creates a new anonymous class definition.

Answer (score 2):

On my device it's - `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()`

(not [1] but [2])

Comment: Check other question and my answer stackoverflow.com/a/8592871/658826 - this one gives you the right method name whatever the index is.