# How to get current method name not from the current Thread at runtime using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

```
class Foo{
    static void fooMethod1(){
        // do something
    }
    static void fooMethod2(){
        // do something
    }
    static void fooMethod3(){
        // do something
    }
}

class bar{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Foo.fooMethod1();
        Foo.fooMethod2();
        Foo.fooMethod3();
    }
}
```

Using reflection, how to know (without knowing method name) that fooMethod1 || 2 || 3 is called (not from the current Thread)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the name of the current executing method java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method-java)

Comment: No idea what you mean by an "event" there.  You want to be notified when any arbitrary method is called?  If so, aspects will be your only hope (not that I'd recommend it).

Comment: you've confused me even more.  Why would we be using a loop?

Comment: You want to call from the outside of the executing thread to find out what function it is executing

Comment: @KirkWoll sorry. I want to know when a method is called at runtime (but not a specific one), in my example I will get "Foo.fooMethod1" then "Foo.fooMethod2" and "Foo.fooMethod3".

Comment: Please write that in the question

Comment: Reflection mechanism is a static structure analysis tool. I doubt it'll help you. Agree with Kirk Woll, you can instrument your code using AOP (check AspectJ for example - http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to insert an aspect at execution join point.

Comment: @KirkWoll it is not a duplicate. What to do if i'm not in the current Thread?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you aren't writing some kind of debugging tool, perhaps you should have your threads talk to each other? Perhaps using an observer? To me, that seems like a much more straight forward, simple and easy-to-understand solution.