# How to make a Spring Controller detect unexpected request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I make a Spring `@Controller` return a `400` status code if the client sends any unexpected request parameters?

For example, I have this

```
    public ResponseEntity<String> recommend(
        @RequestParam(value = "max-age-seconds", required = false) Long maxAgeSeconds) {
        ...
    }
```

And the client may have a typo in `max-age-seconds`, which my application won't recognise and then fallback to the default max age I chose at a later time.

I know I could get the list of all the request parameters with `request.getParameterNames()` and check one by one, but I'm looking for a neater and more efficient solution.

EDIT: I just found out that 4 years ago it [didn't have a built-in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010176/spring-mvc-how-to-check-that-no-unexpected-query-string-parameters-has-been-pa), I wonder if it's still the case.

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution... you need to loop through request params and chek if there are unexpected parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about you call the method `request.getParameterMap()` and then check that the size of your Map is 1 the key equals "max-age-seconds" and you can even validate the value if you wish. if any of your validations goes wrong then return 400 (or may be 300 with error message "**This is Sparta!**"). (the last part is a joke...)