# Is there an easy way to reject unexpected request parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a REST endpoint accepting some request parameters (let's call them `one` and `two`), all optional.
I would like to send a `400 Bad Request` response if one of them is misspelled (say `tow` instead of `two`). That would be the same thing as checking for unexpected parameters (like `three`).

So I would send `200` on:

- `GET /`
- `GET /?one=1`
- `GET /?two=2`
- `GET /?one=1&two=2`

And I would send `400` on:

- `GET /?tow=2`
- `GET /?three=3`

How could I do this easily with Spring? I know how to specify *expected* parameters, but what about the *unexpected* ones?

My first idea was to have some sort of dictionary of allowed values and check it explicitly, but I would have to do this on every request method. There's got to be a better way.

```
@RestController
public class StrictController {

    private static final String[] ALLOWED_PARAMS = { "one", "two" };

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> strict(
            @RequestParam(name = "one", required = false) String one,
            @RequestParam(name = "two", required = false) String two,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            if (!paramAllowed(paramNames.nextElement())) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
    }

    private boolean paramAllowed(String paramName) {
        for (String allowedName : ALLOWED_PARAMS) {
            if (allowedName.toLowerCase().equals(paramName.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want to try this out, I have [a MVCE](https://gitlab.com/dev-samples/strict-request-param).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010176/spring-mvc-how-to-check-that-no-unexpected-query-string-parameters-has-been-pa) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you for the link! I added [a branch](https://gitlab.com/dev-samples/strict-request-param/-/tree/handler_interceptor) on my MVCE with the solution inspired by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018783/479288) on that other question.