# How to Get the Method/Function Call Trace for a Specific Run?

Tags: java, javascript, profile, profiler, jprofiler

Given a Java or JavaScript program, after its execution, print out a sequence of calls. The calls are in invocation order. E.g.

```
main()
{  A();
}

A()
{  B();
   C();
}
```

Then the call trace should be:

```
main -> A() -> B() -> C()
```

Is there any tool that can profile and output this kind of information? It seems this is common a need for debugging or performance tuning.

I noticed that some profilers can do this, but I prefer a simpler/easy-to-use one.

Thanks!

Comment: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: So... after 2 years I still don't know if this is about Java or JavaScript...

Answer (score 2):

An IDE will the job for you. For example, eclipse is a widely used IDE for java programming and if you using it, you can know the hierarchy of calls which lead to a call to specific method.

Try selecting a method, right click and select '**Open call Hieracrhy**' or **Ctrl+Alt+H**. 
This is not the kind of profiler you might be looking, but will help you in knowing the call hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

In Java putting:

```
new Throwable().printStackTrace();
```

Will get you the trace upto the call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace a function in **JavaScript**, you can use the *Developer Tools* in Webkit browsers, or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Or you can do this:

```
function A(){
    debugger;
    B();
    C();
}
```

**Note:** [Java is not JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method) question. Its similar to what you are looking for, "simpler/easy-to-use one"