# Check if the method is invoked

Tags: java, methods, osgi, aop

I am trying to create a logging `OSGi` bundle, which would be able to log input, output, exception (if any) parameters of all the methods which are marked with specific annotation.

I have tried to set up the `Spring` `AOP` logging in `OSGi` but I was unsuccessful.

All I need to know is how to determine when the method is being called? For example I have scanned all methods in a class which are annotated with my annotation and I have those methods in array or list.

For example there are three methods: `getStatus`, `getDetails`, `getSomething`. And the user invokes `getDetails` method, so how should I know when this method is invoked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method/8592871#8592871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting method calls requires you to [instrument your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29). If you want to do this at runtime this requires byte-code manipulation (which is what Spring AOP does, as far as I know). Alternatively you could instrument your code at compile-time using a custom preprocessing step that generates the instrumented Java-code, but I don't know if that is much easier.

I guess your best bet is to try and Spring AOP working.