# Can Java's method "know" its own name?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the name of the current executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

Is there a way in `Java` for a given method to know its own name? If so, how can it be referenced from inside the method?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to do this or are you just curious?

Comment: I'd like to pass along the function name to the Timer class, which can intelligently report on time taken by a given method, without hardcoding

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Comment: @Jam, not sure you're going about it in the right way to time a particular method, because it's going to be difficult to time it if you're already in it.

Comment: I am looking for an estimate, but yes, i see what you're saying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine it by analyzing stack trace. But it may carry quite significant performance penalty. In AOP universe you can also have aspect that will determine method name and store it in some kind of context.

In stack trace method you would do something like

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.fillInStackTrace();
e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

or (as suggested in comment)

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new exception. `Thread` can return a stack trace using `getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Actually, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName(); will return "getStackTrace".  getStackTrace()[1] is probably what you want - the name of the routine which is calling getStackTrace().  In my case, I wanted to know the name to the routine which called the current routine, so [2] was my answer.

Comment: @rcprcp Code above will have to be placed in method that wants to know its name. You will always need to adjust stacktrace if you put more utility methods on top of it. When I have to do something like this, I just pass a parameter that tells the amount of adjustment.

Comment: @AlexGitelman--(1) How do I "adjust stacktrace"? (2) What do you mean by "put more utility methods on top of it" (3) What sort of parameter and its value tells the "amount of adjustment"?

Comment: @DSlomer64 If your method is `foobar()` and you place the code above in it, you take stack element at offset 0 to get `foobar`. But if you create utility method `getMethodName()` that you call from `foobar()` then offset will be 1 since at offset 0 you will find `getMethodName`. 
If you have more nested methods, you will have to adjust more.

Answer (score 4):

The first element of the stack trace (`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069074/372643)) should tell you in which method you currently are at runtime.