# Java method watchpoints in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to log something to some Eclipse view after/before specific methods are entered in my Java project.

Is this possible?

- I don't want it to break to the Debugger, so no breakpoints
- AspectJ might be a last resort, but can you provide some quick'n'dirty tutorial with it, as it is quite foreign to me

*ADDITIONAL INFO 1:* I am using Eclipse 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a normal breakpoint in the method, add a condition like

```
System.out.println("hit the method"); return false;
```

That breakpoint will always be evaluated, but it will not stop the debugger. You can use the same technique also with a method breakpoint (instead of line breakpoint) and there you can additionally specify whether it shall be evaluated on entering or leaving the method.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to get the current method's name in the condition? All I can think of is something like creating a new Exception and getting the method at the top of the stack trace...

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() avoids the costly exception. More alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Comment: Just for others doing the same: in case of Android, System.out in breakpoint conditionals will go to LogCat! Works great!