# Get the name of method at runtime

Tags: class, runtime

For the Log purpose, I want to know the name of method at runtime.

Ex.

```
public void methodA(){
Log.e("INSIDE", "//some code here to get the name of methodA");
}
```

If I will get the name of method at runtime, it will reduce my repetitive task of inserting same log in different methods.

Comment: Mention the reason for downvote please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the name of the current executing method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is Java... If that is the case, this returns the name of the method you are currently in.

```
String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()
```

Be careful though, don't put this in a method, because then that will return the name of that method. You could also use this:

```
public String getMethodName() {
    return new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
}
```

This observes the second element of the stack trace, returning the correct method name.

**UPDATE:**

Though the first does what it takes, this is nicer: doesn't involve creating a new object at least:

```
Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
```

**Warning** I have to mention that all this however has an adverse impact on performance...