# Shorter method for getting the name of the current method dynamically

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to get the name of the current method without having to create a blank object. Is there a way to do this? This would tidy up our logging code.

Here is what we do now:

```
new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]`?

Since this enables you to examine higher levels of the stack trace, you could easily wrap this in a helper method (see below). It also gives you the option to get quite a bit more info than just the method name, such as the file name, line number etc.

**edit** The helper method could look something like this (thanks @Esailija):

```
public static String getMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}
```

Comment: Sr. 0 means current method, 1 means call method

Comment: @dreamcrash: Have you actually tried it? I have.

Comment: `public static String methodName() {
  return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
 }` Works great for me

Comment: @NPE I am sorry, you were right 0 will return getStackTrace. +1 For the inconvenient.

Comment: @dreamcrash  upvote your comment, because I wonder why we should use [1] and lazy to check what [0] will return :)

Comment: Check other question and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8592871/658826 - this one gives you the right method name whatever the index is.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()
```

contains the last method call, but is not shorter that

```
new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName
```

I am not aware of a sorter way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `thread.currentThread().getStacktrace()[0].getMethodName()`. But this even takes more time than `new Throwable().getStacktrace()` (see http://alexradzin.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/how-slow-getstacktrace-is.html)