# Get function name at runtime in android (java)

Tags: java, android, runtime

I want a method in android: `getCallerName()`. It will print the name of the method which use it. Example: if I have a method:

```
void doSomething(){
    getCallerName(); // This line will print "doSomething"
} 
//or another example
void foo(){
   getCallerName(); // this line will print "foo"
}
```

Can anyone tell me that I can do that at runtime? And how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Comment: What you're calling a _function_ is referred to as a _method_ in Java...