# how to find a method is currently executing in java?

Tags: java, android

I want to know how i can find a particular method is currently running,if it is currently running i don't want to execute another function.

```
Class myclass extending someclass{
  private void method A(){

  //somthing here
  }

  private void method B(){

  //somthing here
  }

  private void method C(){
   B();//don't want to call B if A is running 

  //somthing here
  }
}
```

boolean flag ia not working.I don't want static boolean flag.I am calling different function when orientation of mobile device changes but in one of four orientation i was to check whether a function is currently running or not.

Comment: did you tried setting a flag which gets initialized when A is running and resets to null when A's execution is over

Comment: What do you mean running? Do you mean another thread is running that method or simply that the method C was called from within method A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the name of the current executing method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

Comment: @Amrendra can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: Are you sure you don't simply want to use a synchronization primitive (such as locking, a semaphore, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link

[Getting the name of the current executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

also you can set a flag which gets initialized when A is running and resets to null when A's execution is over

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
AtomicInteger aCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

private void A() {
    aCount.incrementAndGet();
    try {
        //
    } finally {
        aCount.decrementAndGet();
    }
}

private void B() {
}

private void C() {
    if (aCount.intValue() == 0) {
        B();
    }
}
```