# Is it possible to refer to the @RequestMapping value in the annotated method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Given a method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/foo"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMappingValueInMethod() {
    log.debug("requested "+foo); //how can I make this refer to /foo programmatically?
    return "bar";
}
```

The use case is for refactoring some lengthly code.  I have several GET methods doing roughly the same thing and only the request mapping value is different.

I've looked at using path variables, but this is not really what I want (unless there's some clever use of it that I don't see).  I could also get a value from the `HttpServletRequest` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc), but not sure whether there's a better way.

Comment: When you say 'I've looked at using path variables, but this is not really what I want' are you sure. What about ... `@RequestMapping(value = {"/{path}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMappingValueInMethod(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
        log.debug("requested "+path);
        return "bar";
    }`

Comment: Please go into detail about your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

With [HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934347/springmvc-how-to-get-the-value-of-requestmapping-in-the-function/27938709#27938709).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fooMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE).toString();
    System.out.println("path foo: " + path);
    return "bar";
}
```

**Solution 2**

With [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192647/2442133).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fooMethod2() {
    try {
        Method m = YourClassController.class.getMethod("fooMethod2");
        String path = m.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
        System.out.println("foo2 path: " + path);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "bar";
}
```

If you want get path from class (instead method) you can use:

```
String path = YourClassController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();
```

**Solution 3**

With [@PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697756/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-the-requestmapping-value-in-the-annotated-method#comment55167418_33697756).

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/{foo3}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String fooMethod3(@PathVariable("foo3") String path) {
        path = "/" + path; // if you need "/"
        System.out.println("foo3 path: " + path);
        return "bar";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this would be putting the array directly in the request mapping i am assuming this is what you want.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/foo","/foo1","/foo2"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMappingValueInMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.debug("requested "+request.getRequestURI()); 
    return request.getRequestURI();
}
```

Then name the jsp files similar to the uri or other wise you could store the mapping between the request uri and the name of the page in the db .