# Fully qualified method name of the current method

Tags: java, reflection, callback

I want to get all the annotations of the current method, for that I need method instance so that I can [get annotation from method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29).

I am able to [Get Current Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method/5891326#5891326) name, but I need fully qualified name of the method or method instance.

I am also interested in other Object oriented solutions, for example call back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should work for you:

```
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    // The 2nd element of the array is the current method
    String className = stackTrace[1].getClassName();
    Class clazz = Class.forName(stackTrace[1].getClassName());

    String methodName = stackTrace[1].getClassName()+"."+stackTrace[1].getMethodName();
    String simpleMethodName = stackTrace[1].getMethodName();

    // This will work only when there are no parameters for the method
    Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(simpleMethodName, null);

    // Fetch the annotations 
    Annotation[] annotations = m.getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

Comment: Is there any to get the signature of the method?