# Dynamically printing fully qualified class name along with method name

Tags: java

I want output `com.iland.Action.LoginAction.doLogin()`

The code should be effective for any class

for example

```
package com.iland.Action

Class LoginAction{

  void doLogin()
  {
      System.out.println("");//what contens should be printed in sop
  }
}
```

I would like to print dynamically fully qualified class name and the method name which is being executed.

Comment: Maybe this can help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code inside your function body:

```
String Name=this.getClass().toString();
String fullName=Name.substring(Name.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
System.out.println(fullName);// fully qualified class name.
System.out.println(fullName.substring(0,fullName.lastIndexOf(".")));// package name
System.out.println(fullName+new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());// fully qualified method name
```

For more information on getStackTrace, refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29)

Comment: How to get package name

Comment: @AmanArora  this code i am using while catching exception. Could you tell me how to get line number of exception code

Comment: @xrcwrn Line number of exception code?.. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am using this code for logging                                                   `try{.........} catch (SQLException e) {
            status = "failure";
            System.out.println("Exception  " + e);
            LogErrorBusiness.log(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName(), new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName(), e.toString());` along with generating fully qualified class name and method name i want to get line number where exception is being thrown

Comment: try this `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code fragment that can help you.

```
StackTraceElement trace = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0];
trace.getMethodName(); // returns method name
trace.getClassName(); // returns class name
```

Comment: Can we get fully qualified method name as I need `com.iland.Action.LoginAction.doLogin()`

Answer (score 0):

It will show you class name with packege and method name

```
  System.out.println(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());//  class name
        System.out.println(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());// method name
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(stackTraceElements[1].getClassName());//class name
        System.out.println(stackTraceElements[1].getMethodName());//method name
```