# How to get the name of the containing function

Tags: java

In C++, you can use `__FUNCTION_NAME__` to get the name of the function that contains `__FUNCTION_NAME__`.

Is there an equivalent in Java? It *could*, in Java, be possible to do something with `this` and reflection. Is there something simpler though?

Comment: did you try Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() ?

Comment: @Alessio: That's neat if a little expensive: and a candidate as an answer.

Comment: @Alessio this doesn't always work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method

Comment: you're right, I've used in a project and I didn't know that may not work

Answer (score 0):

> Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
>   will usually contain the method you’re calling it from but there are pitfalls

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[ste.length - 1 - depth].getMethodName();
```

depth = 0 (zero) will give current method

also

```
System.out.println((new Throwable()).getStackTrace()[0].toString());
```

Sample output:

```
com.junk.Junk3.main(Junk3.java:12)
```