# Find the caller of a method (reflection) in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I want to recover in Java the instance of the caller.
Here is my code

```
class A {
    void methodA() {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b.methodB(); //needs to be the same instance ie "this"
    }
}

class B {
    A methodB() {
        //Here the code (with reflection) I need
        A a = getPreviousInstanceCaller();
        return A
    }
}
```

Does it exist in Java a way to do that ? Maybe with reflection ?

Comment: What if the method was called from a `static` method? Look into the `StackTraceElement` class. You can find the class it was called from, but there wasn't necessarily an instance involved.

Comment: You can examine the stacktrace and get the element in the first 'hop'. As far as I know there is no other solution because a method call isn't something that's retained (except for the stacktrace).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need reflection for this. You need one of these methods.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29

Note that the ordering of the stack trace elements (0, 1, 2, etc.)
may vary in different versions of the JDK. Meaning in some versions
element 0 may be the top-most element, while in others it may be the
bottom-most one. This is an important thing to have in mind.

See here for more details.

[Getting the name of the current executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)