# How to automate the method name in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

My code will auto get the className and method name.
This will helps me to identify the test case.
My code look like this

```
final String CLASS_NAME = new Object() {
  }.getClass().getName();

@Test
  public void bigNumTest() {

    final String METHOD_NAME = new Object() {
    }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
    String testName = CLASS_NAME + "/" + METHOD_NAME + "\n the input is";

    long bigNumber = 123456789l;
    assertEquals(testName+bigNumber, CollatzConjectureLength.main(bigNumber), conjecture(bigNumber));
 }
```

However, it's look busy so I wanna hide the automation.
e.g.

```
@Test
 public void bigNumTest(){
  long bigNumber = 123456789l;
 assertEqualsWithId(CollatzConjectureLength.main(bigNumber),conjecture(bigNumber))
}
```

However, I cannot call

```
 final String METHOD_NAME = new Object() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

from the other method

the other solution is from [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

```
public static String getMethodName(final int depth)
{
  final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

  //System. out.println(ste[ste.length-depth].getClassName()+"#"+ste[ste.length-depth].getMethodName());
  // return ste[ste.length - depth].getMethodName();  //Wrong, fails for depth = 0
  return ste[ste.length - 1 - depth].getMethodName(); //Thank you Tom Tresansky
}
```

This solution may got the wrong method name due to the deep of method call?

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JUnit 4.7 or above you could try this:

```
public class NameRuleTest {
  @Rule
  public TestName name = new TestName();

  @Test
  public void testA() {
    assertEquals("testA", name.getMethodName());
  }

  @Test
  public void testB() {
    assertEquals("testB", name.getMethodName());
  }
}
```

copied from here:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#testname-rule

Comment: I strongly suggest making the `name` field `final`