# Logback - Print out method name that called the log method

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

In my example, I have the following code:

```java
package com.example.somepackage;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);
        logger.info("Example message.");
    }
}
```

I want it to output to the console like this minimal example:

```
com.example.somepackage.Example.main Example message.
```

The only thing I need is either:

- a pattern to put into the `logback.xml` file or
- instructions on further code I need to add to my example code scenario

If extra code is used instead of a XML configuration pattern, please also provide information on how to pair these two, so one can still use patterns for time, log level, etc. in addition to the method name being printed out.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `%M` pattern.
See the [Logback docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#method)
for all patterns that you could use.
Note, however, that these docs also say:

> Generating the method name is not particularly fast. Thus, its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample appender that logs method name and line number:

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %green([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) (%logger{50}.%M\(%line\)) - (%msg%n)
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a more current solution, I wrote a **maven-plugin** addressing this issue, while not generating any performance issues either:
https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin

This plugin **injects the class name, optionally also the method name and source code line number into all SLF4J log statements at compile time** (see [configuration](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin#configuration)).
All you need to do is to add the `callerInformation` MDC parameter to your log-pattern (see [Code Example](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin#code-example)) and add the plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>io.github.philkes</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
        <goal>inject</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for building and sharing this!