# How to create a .txt file with the name of the class that called the method?

Tags: java, file, class

I am new to programming, so let's see if I can explain this well enough.

I am making a Java package. In one of the classes there is a method that creates a file. The name of that file I have it set up as "file.txt", but I want to change it.

Let's say there is a user working on a new project and he imports the library package (the one I am working on). I want for the file that is created to take the name of the class in which the user is working on. For example if the user calls it in a class named Main, I want the file to be called main.txt or Main.txt.

If this is not clear enough please let me know, I'll try to explain it better.

Thanks

Edit: I've tried the getClass().getSimpleName() but it's not working exactly like I want it to. The method is located inside a library called `library` and the class is called `Main.class` but is being used by a use that imported the library `library` and is working on a class called `SuperMario.class` I want the text file to be called `SuperMario.txt` instead with `getClass().getSimpleName()` applied to my method the file will be called `Main.txt`, because that is the name of the class the method is in. Unfortunately I can't have the method pass the name as a parameter. Can anyone think of a way around this?

Comment: You might be able to modify the accepted answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method) to make it work for you.

Comment: @resueman Thanks, I've been trying to play around with it, but haven't gotten any luck. This stuff goes over my head sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your library, use stacktrace :

```
public class Called {

public static void calledMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName());
        // stackTrace 0 is get stack trace.
        // stack trace 1 is calledMethod
        // stack trace 2 is the calling method aka main in
    }
}
```

The result will be

```
eu.plop.test.TestClass
```

You had to search after stacktrace to see if you want the filename, class name, method's name... and then some string works to remove the package if unused.