# How to know which test is currently running

Tags: unit-testing, sbt, scalatest

We have thousands of tests, and one is stuck (some infinite loop probably).

I'd like to know which tests is running but sbt only displays tests that are done. It also shows the tests titles, but as I said, we have too many tests to know which title the stuck test is part of.

Comment: you can query the stacktrace to get the current running test method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Maybe in an answer. I don't know what you mean by "query", and to which stacktrace you are making reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-name-of-executing-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [runner arguments](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner) to configure a file reporter

```
-f output.txt
```

in combination with unformatted or "ugly" mode flag `U` which

> Rather than attempting to make the output look as pretty and
>   human-readable as possible, unformatted mode will just print out
>   verbose information about each event as it arrives, helping you track
>   down the problem you are trying to debug.

and then tail the output file during test execution

```
tail -f output.txt
```

which will show events in realtime as they are happening as opposed to at the end of testing.

Now given following example

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-fU", "output.txt")

class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Hello object" should "satisfy case 1" in {
    assert(true)
  }

  it should "satisfy case 2" in {
    assert(true)
  }

  it should "satisfy case 3 (stuck here)" in {
    while(true) { /* do something forever */ }
    assert(true)
  }

  it should "satisfy case 4" in {
    assert(true)
  }
}
```

then `tail -f output.txt` outputs

```
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
Suite Starting - HelloSpec
Scope Opened - HelloSpec: The Hello object
Test Starting - HelloSpec: The Hello object should satisfy case 1
Test Succeeded - HelloSpec: The Hello object should satisfy case 1
Test Starting - HelloSpec: The Hello object should satisfy case 2
Test Succeeded - HelloSpec: The Hello object should satisfy case 2
Test Starting - HelloSpec: The Hello object should satisfy case 3 (stuck here)
```

where we can identify the stuck test on the last line.

Comment: To run it from sbt command line, use something like `sbt "test-only -- -fU output.txt"` (see "specifying scalatest argument" section of http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt).
When there is lot's of tests, it's quite complicated to trace. But it does the trick.

Comment: I've put all the command I used here: https://gist.github.com/julien-diener/3ac5ba3e34dac6ff965b1cd3cba09d13