# How to get all possible callers of a method in Java - like call hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, call-hierarchy

Say I have a method m in a class. I'm trying to find all the methods that call m in the whole project. Similar to eclipse's call hierarchy tool, except I need it to output a list/array of Methods. I need it statically so I dont think a stack trace works. Is there any way to implement this, maybe using reflection?

I attached link to an example of Eclipse's call hierarchy tool, finding all the methods that mention the method barking() from the class Dog. (Dog.hungry() and Cat.scratching() call barking()).

[image]

Comment: I think this has been already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" java reflection will probably not be of any help on this.

I would try using the open source [Reflection](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

You can search for a method with via:

```
Set<Member> usages = reflections.getMethodUsages(Method.class)
```

Comment: Im trying to clone the project into my eclipse so i can make a jar out of it but it keeps telling me its empty. I'm not very familiar with adding open source libs. If I use maven to install, will it be a plugin that opens me a new eclipse window at runtime?

Comment: Try using maven ... it will add it as a dependency (jar) of its own. But I'm sure you can download it directly and add it as a local dependency to a Eclipse project. Have you googled it? ... like here: https://code.google.com/p/reflections/downloads/list

Comment: Hey Drejc, so I downladed the latest jar from the link, and added it to my jars file, and went into my java build path and added it there as well. But when I use reflections it asks me if I want to add "import org.reflections.Reflections;" and not "import static org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.*;". When I do import either of them, "Set<Member> usages = reflections.getMethodUsages(Method.class)" gives me an error. Any idea why?? Thanks again

Comment: Here are a couple screenshots of what I tried and failed with. Im also not sure if I am constructing reflections properly
http://imgur.com/a/0YBJH

Comment: Really hard to tell whats "wrong", but I would suggest to go with some easy examples first, if you take a look at the tests inside the Reflections project you will find plenty use cases. Just a quick glance and I found this:  Reflections reflections = new Reflections(TestModel.class, new FieldAnnotationsScanner());  Probably the way to go ... using a different scanner of course.