# How can I get all methods which are called by a testMethod? (Java, TestNG, IAnnotationTransformer)

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, testng

I'm currently using IAnnotationTransformer to exclude all tests listed in an XML which contain a particular string in their name, for example:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if(testMethod.getName().contains("StringGoesHere")){
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

This works perfectly well, however due to the naming convention of my tests, and the vast amount of tests which I need to exclude, the ideal solution would be to find a way to exclude the test if it calls upon a particular method. For example, I want to exclude all tests which call upon the method .clickUserSettings() shown below:

```
@Test
public void editUserDetailsOnStackOverflow() {
    final StackOverflow so = stackOverflow.loginAsMe()
            .clickUserSettings()
            .changeUserEmail()
            .clickSave()
            .assertChangeSuccessful();
}
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this? I feel like I've explored all other avenues (classes, packages, testMethods, groups, xml, etc) And the reason it has to be done in this way is because I currently have 40,000 tests (15,000 of which will likely be excluded depending on the browserMode variable set by the tester) This is the general idea I was hoping to achieve:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if(testMethod.getAllCalledMethods.contains(".clickUserSettings()")){
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

If this can be done it will solve my issue,

Cheers

Comment: Why groups are not fit for purpose?

Comment: Well - nothing out of the box will give this to you.  Consider writing an external script which runs as a pre-test thing or beforesuite - generates a list of these methods - which you can disable in your annotation transformer.  Some ways :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java.  You can do a grep in the files or a quick loop of your included tests..to think of a few solutions

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with TestNG. TestNG has visibility only to the methods that are annotated with its annotations and its not aware of the code path that a TestNG method traverses during its course of execution. [ Here I am assuming that the method `clickUserSettings()` is a utility method that your `@Test` methods perhaps call into, as part of its execution ]

So you have a couple of options

1. Resort to using groups wherein all methods that call into `clickUserSettings()` as part of a particular group and then exclude that group from execution.
2. Create your own custom annotation, annotate all methods that invoke `clickUserSettings()` using this annotation, and then modify your current `AnnotationTransformer` to look for this annotation at either the method level or at the class level.