# Is it possible to scan a package hierarchy at runtime to find where a method is called?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a utility method which reads a value from the environment and returns a default if the property is not defined.

```
public String Env.getString(String name, String defaultValue);
```

I would like to scan the whole application (a REST microservice), on demand, to list all calls to that method. The goal is to be able to generate a dump of all the environment properties in use and the current  values.

How can I use reflection (or some other scheme) to seach all classes in a given hierarchy to find calls to the utility method? As I also have `getInteger`, `getBoolean`etc an even better solution would find all methods like `Env.get...`

Comment: it is not an easy task, can take another approach - modify this method so that it records what method has called it?

Comment: @AdamSiemion Bad advice. The job of that method is to provide a property, not to track its usage. And worse: two workloads might use different properties, so you can never be **sure** that the tracking information you receive is **complete**.

Comment: Would using Aspects be a viable solution? While you can't do this with reflection necessarily, you should be able to use aspectJ and define a pointcut targeting the `Env.getString` call.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of that application? Or at least the Jar of that application?

Answer (score 3):

Reflection doesn't help you: that only allows you to query the **structure** of classes and method signatures. It does not give you access to the **body** of methods, thus you have no way to identify *method invocations* from reflection.

One solution: use a decent IDE. Eclipse or IntelliJ give you *one click* solutions to "find usages" for methods.

If you want something that works from the command line, you would be looking for tools that give you access to the actual bytecode. A stupid brute force way could be to use `javap` to disassemble all class files into text, and then `grep` to search within that output. More sophisticated approaches would use tools like the [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) library, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java) for your usecase.

Comment: the idea came from using eclipse as finding calls is very easy. I was hoping that eclipse uses a mechanism which I can also use at runtime.

Comment: @paul IDEs spend a lot of time and energy to incorporate compiler knowledge. Basically they create an "index" where they lookup such information. Maybe there APIs to externalize that information, but I am not aware of any. But I am also not an expert in such areas.