# How to tell which JNI libraries are actually loaded by the JVM on startup of a JDK 17 application?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-arguments, java-17, native-code

I started my app with the JVM option `-Xlog:library=trace` - [based on advice in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548200/how-to-find-native-libraries-in-a-jdk-17-application-that-are-used-via-jni) - to see which native libraries are being loaded.

But the output is pretty confusing - see below:

```
[0.021s][info][library] Loaded library libjsvml.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0ca000
[0.042s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_nio in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.045s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnio.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.046s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.046s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_fs_UnixNativeDispatcher_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.047s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_fs_UnixNativeDispatcher_getcwd in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.049s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_fs_UnixNativeDispatcher_stat0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.052s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_zip in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.053s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.054s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.054s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.055s][info][library] Found Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.056s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.057s][info][library] Found Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.063s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_inflateBytesBytes in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.067s][info][library] Found Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_inflateBytesBytes in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.068s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_reset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.069s][info][library] Found Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_reset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.074s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_zip in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.117s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_end in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.117s][info][library] Found Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_end in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.211s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_jimage in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.213s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c002790
[0.216s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c002790
[0.220s][info][library] Failed to find Java_jdk_internal_jimage_NativeImageBuffer_getNativeMap in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.221s][info][library] Failed to find Java_jdk_internal_jimage_NativeImageBuffer_getNativeMap in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.222s][info][library] Found Java_jdk_internal_jimage_NativeImageBuffer_getNativeMap in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c002790
[0.531s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_net in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.532s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnet.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0ed2f0
[0.533s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0ed2f0
[0.534s][info][library] Found inet_pton in library with handle 0x0000000000000000
[0.534s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_nio in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.535s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.536s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_iovMax in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.536s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileChannelImpl_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.537s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileChannelImpl_maxDirectTransferSize0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.538s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.538s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeThread_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.539s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeThread_current in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.540s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileKey_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.541s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileKey_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.542s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_lock0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.542s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_release0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.543s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_native-platform in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.544s][info][library] Loaded library /root/.gradle/native/e1d6ef7f7dcc3fd88c89a11ec53ec762bb8ba0a96d01ffa2cd45eb1d1d8dd5c5/linux-amd64/libnative-platform.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.545s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.546s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_NativeLibraryFunctions_getVersion in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.552s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_native-platform-curses in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.557s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_native-platform-curses in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.560s][info][library] Loaded library /root/.gradle/native/e1d6ef7f7dcc3fd88c89a11ec53ec762bb8ba0a96d01ffa2cd45eb1d1d8dd5c5/linux-amd64-ncurses6/libnative-platform-curses.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.561s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.562s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_getVersion in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.565s][info][library] Failed to find Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixTerminalFunctions_isatty in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.565s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixTerminalFunctions_isatty in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.567s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_initTerminal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.568s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_hideCursor in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.568s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_showCursor in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.570s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_defaultForeground in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.571s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_boldOn in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.571s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_dimOn in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.572s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_reset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.572s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_down in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.573s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_up in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.574s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_left in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.574s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_right in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.575s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_startLine in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.575s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_TerminfoFunctions_clearToEndOfLine in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.666s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_management in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.667s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libmanagement.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.668s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.669s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_management_ext in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.670s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libmanagement_ext.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.671s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.673s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVersion0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.674s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVersion0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.674s][info][library] Found Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVersion0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.675s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_initOptionalSupportFields in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.675s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_initOptionalSupportFields in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.676s][info][library] Found Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_initOptionalSupportFields in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.682s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getStartupTime in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.683s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getStartupTime in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.684s][info][library] Found Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getStartupTime in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.687s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVmArguments0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.687s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVmArguments0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.687s][info][library] Found Java_sun_management_VMManagementImpl_getVmArguments0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.702s][info][library] Failed to find Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixProcessFunctions_getPid in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.703s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixProcessFunctions_getPid in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.782s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_net in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.782s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.784s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.785s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_net in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.786s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_InetAddress_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.787s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_InetAddress_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.789s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_InetAddressImplFactory_isIPv6Supported in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.789s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_InetAddressImplFactory_isIPv6Supported in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.790s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_Inet4Address_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.790s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_Inet4Address_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.791s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_Inet6Address_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.791s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_Inet6Address_init in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.792s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.793s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.798s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_isLoopback0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.803s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_isLoopback0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.804s][info][library] Failed to find Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_boundInetAddress0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.804s][info][library] Found Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_boundInetAddress0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.806s][info][library] Failed to find JNI_OnLoad_extnet in library with handle 0x00007f9a83c232e0
[0.807s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libextnet.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.807s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.808s][info][library] Found Java_jdk_net_LinuxSocketOptions_quickAckSupported0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.809s][info][library] Found Java_jdk_net_LinuxSocketOptions_keepAliveOptionsSupported0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.809s][info][library] Found Java_jdk_net_LinuxSocketOptions_incomingNapiIdSupported0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.810s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.810s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.811s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.811s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollinValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.812s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollinValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.812s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollinValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.813s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_polloutValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.813s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_polloutValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.814s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_polloutValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.814s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollerrValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.815s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollerrValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.815s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollerrValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.816s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollhupValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.816s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollhupValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.820s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollhupValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.820s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollnvalValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.823s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollnvalValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.827s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollnvalValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.827s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollconnValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.828s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollconnValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.829s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollconnValue in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.829s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isExclusiveBindAvailable in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.830s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isExclusiveBindAvailable in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.831s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isExclusiveBindAvailable in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.831s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isIPv6Available0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.832s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isIPv6Available0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.832s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isIPv6Available0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.833s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_socket0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.833s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_socket0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.837s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_socket0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.843s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_setfdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.843s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_setfdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.844s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_setfdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.844s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.845s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.845s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdVal in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.846s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.846s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.847s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.847s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.848s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.848s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_AFINET6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.849s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr4 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.850s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr4 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.850s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr4 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.855s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.859s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.859s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofSockAddr6 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.860s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.860s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.861s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_sizeofFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.861s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.862s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.862s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetFamily in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.863s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.863s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.864s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.864s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.865s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.866s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin4Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.866s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.867s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.870s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Port in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.871s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.871s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.872s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6Addr in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.872s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6ScopeId in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.873s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6ScopeId in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.874s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6ScopeId in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.874s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6FlowInfo in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.875s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6FlowInfo in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.875s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_NativeSocketAddress_offsetSin6FlowInfo in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.877s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_bind0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.880s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_bind0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.884s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_bind0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.895s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localInetAddress in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.895s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localInetAddress in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.896s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localInetAddress in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.896s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localPort in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.897s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localPort in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.897s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_localPort in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.898s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isReusePortAvailable0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.898s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isReusePortAvailable0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.898s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_isReusePortAvailable0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.900s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_setIntOption0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.900s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_setIntOption0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.900s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_setIntOption0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.914s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_configureBlocking in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.914s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_configureBlocking in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.914s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_configureBlocking in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.915s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_connect0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.915s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_connect0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.916s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_connect0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.917s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollConnect in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.920s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollConnect in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.920s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_Net_pollConnect in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.924s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdLimit in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.926s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdLimit in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.926s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_fdLimit in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.927s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventSize in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.928s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventSize in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.928s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventSize in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.929s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventsOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.929s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventsOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.929s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_eventsOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.930s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_dataOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.930s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_dataOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.931s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_dataOffset in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.931s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_create in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.932s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_create in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.932s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_create in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.933s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EventFD_eventfd0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.933s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EventFD_eventfd0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.939s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EventFD_eventfd0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.956s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_ctl in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.966s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_ctl in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.971s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_ctl in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.976s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_write0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.977s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_write0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.977s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_FileDispatcherImpl_write0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.983s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_wait in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.983s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_wait in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.984s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_wait in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.988s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_SocketDispatcher_read0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
[0.988s][info][library] Failed to find Java_sun_nio_ch_SocketDispatcher_read0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.989s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_ch_SocketDispatcher_read0 in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
```

Most of the output is talking about "failed to find" a library. But then I see other lines where it does find the library.

Is there some other argument I should be using to exclude all of the "failed to find" stuff and just see what's actually loaded?

Just to be clear, I only want to see loaded native libraries that are being invoked by Java Native Interface (JNI) because I have evidence that there is a memory leak in the Java application when it calls some native code via JNI.

But this output doesn't shed as much light on the matter as I was hoping.

Or maybe I'm just not reading it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the "Found" and "Failed to find" lines are about symbols/function being looked up in a library.

---

Unified logging (`-Xlog`) also allows you to pipe output to a file:

```
-Xlog:library=info:file=libraries_log.txt
```

And then use `grep` (or `sls` on Windows) on the file to look for "Loaded library":

```
$ grep "Loaded library" ./libraries_log.txt
[0.021s][info][library] Loaded library libjsvml.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0ca000
[0.045s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnio.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0eccb0
[0.053s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libzip.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c024da0
[0.213s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjimage.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c002790
[0.532s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libnet.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c0ed2f0
[0.544s][info][library] Loaded library /root/.gradle/native/e1d6ef7f7dcc3fd88c89a11ec53ec762bb8ba0a96d01ffa2cd45eb1d1d8dd5c5/linux-amd64/libnative-platform.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.560s][info][library] Loaded library /root/.gradle/native/e1d6ef7f7dcc3fd88c89a11ec53ec762bb8ba0a96d01ffa2cd45eb1d1d8dd5c5/linux-amd64-ncurses6/libnative-platform-curses.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c6d0ef0
[0.667s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libmanagement.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c763730
[0.670s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libmanagement_ext.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c76e760
[0.807s][info][library] Loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libextnet.so, handle 0x00007f9a7c7e4fd0
```

All of these libraries are being loaded by the JVM. Note that the JDK also uses JNI itself to implement certain features, so that is why some libraries from the JDK directory are being loaded.

I'm assuming the libraries you're interested in are the `/root/.gradle/native/*` libraries?

---

You could then use the value of the handle, i.e. the hexadecimal value at the end of the line, to search for symbols that are being looked up in this particular library. For example, if I take the handle value of `/root/.gradle/native/*/linux-amd64/libnative-platform.so`, which is `0x00007f9a7c6cad60`. I can use `grep` again to find which symbols the JVM is trying to load from this library:

```
$ grep 0x00007f9a7c6cad60 ./libraries_log.txt
[0.544s][info][library] Loaded library /root/.gradle/native/e1d6ef7f7dcc3fd88c89a11ec53ec762bb8ba0a96d01ffa2cd45eb1d1d8dd5c5/linux-amd64/libnative-platform.so, handle
0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.545s][info][library] Found JNI_OnLoad in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.546s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_NativeLibraryFunctions_getVersion in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.565s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixTerminalFunctions_isatty in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
[0.703s][info][library] Found Java_net_rubygrapefruit_platform_internal_jni_PosixProcessFunctions_getPid in library with handle 0x00007f9a7c6cad60
```

Comment: Oh wow, now that you break it down like that, it makes so much sense. Thanks again, man!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember it correctly, those things "with handle" are not the libraries but the functions to be expected inside a library.

You are interested mainly in those lines beginning with "Loaded library".

Comment: Yep, I see that now. I'm going to go with answer above because of the additional elaboration but thanks for your help!