# Invoking callhierarchy for a method

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an object of type IMethod which represents a method .I want to get the Call Hierarchy of this method . Which methods should i call to get the call hierarchy of a method? Is there any method by which i can do it? I know that i can get it by ctrl+alt+H but i want the code or method for invoking it. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650844/getting-call-hierarchy-of-a-method-using-reflections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with Bozho, you shouldn't need it, you CAN get it, by throwing an exception and catching it, and then do printStackTrace on your exception variable.