# code to get all callers of a method of a Groovy-Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am looking for a way to extract all the methods calling `printc(String)` method from a separate main program.

In IntelliJ IDE I can do so by go to the method `void printc(String txt)` and click `Ctrl+Alt+H` to get the expected results like this:

[image: callers of a given method]([Groovy-java project])

but I would like to implement such functionality in my own program
(without use of an IDE)

For example:

```
package com.controller;


import com.mgr.ServiceBean;
import com.ser.B;
**//Java file**
public class A extends ServiceBean {
    void a() {
    }

    void a1() {
    super.printc("calle of c");
    }

    void a2(B boo) {
        super.printc("calle of c");
    }


}

======

package com.ser

import com.mgr.C
import com.mgr.ServiceBean
**//Groovy file**
public class B extends ServiceBean {
    void b1() {
    }

    void b2() {
        super.printc("calle of c")
    }
}

=====

package com.mgr
**//Groovy file**
trait C
{
    String test() {
        return "test"
    }

    boolean printc(String methodName)  {
        if(methodName!=null)
            return true
        false
    }
}
=========
package com.mgr
**//Groovy file**
class ServiceBean implements C {

}

============

//Need logic which accepts 
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main m=new Main();
        m.FindUsage("C","void printc(String)")
    }
    Collection FindUsage(String ClassName, String methodname){
        // XXX Logic missing
        return **“[A.a1(),A.a2(Integer),B.b2()]”**
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: i can’t use stack trace to get the results as the A, B, C classes are completely different src and I am not running them, main is a separate program.

[How can I find all the methods that call a given method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java) --> doesn't include caller of Groovy classes

Comment: Check out this, I believe this answers your query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650844/getting-call-hierarchy-of-a-method-using-reflections

Comment: As i have mentioned i am looking for a separate main program. I cant use StackTrace as it's not in the same program and I am not running  A, B, C classes.

Comment: So you just want a code analyzer? Have you checked if codenarc can help you with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for a find usage function, take a look at this, it can help you 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-usages-method-options.html

Comment: Oumina, I am looking for a code to implement to get a List of calle methods like https://i.stack.imgur.com/aff5l.png

Answer (score 0):

If all the classes which may come in the desired call hierarchy, are available at run time, then you can traverse over each class and it's methods and create a topological sorted graph, from which you can traverse back the call hierarchy, from the concerned method.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I find all the methods that call a given method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930289/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-call-a-given-method-in-java) provides code for byte code scanning but it fails for the Groovy files, I end up doing a mixture of by reading each and every line in my source code as a string and then parsing them along with ASM bytecode analysis to extract the needed information of java files. 
Note: ASM doesn't work for the groovy files as byte code for java file and groovy file are different, in Groovy file you get a larger .class file compared to java's

Sample code:

```
//stringValue =entire text
//charopen example: { or (
//char close: } or )
private String getFullMethod(String stringValue, String chartOpen, String charClose) {
        String methodName = ''
        int breaceStackIn = 0
        boolean read = true, readOpen = true
        if (stringValue != null) {
            stringValue.eachWithIndex { it, index ->
                if (it.equalsIgnoreCase(chartOpen) && readOpen) {
                    breaceStackIn += 1
                    read = true
                } else if (it.equalsIgnoreCase(charClose) && readOpen) {
                    breaceStackIn -= 1
                    methodName += charClose
                    read = false
                }
                if (read && readOpen) {
                    methodName += it
                }
                if (breaceStackIn == 0 && read == false && readOpen) {
                    readOpen = false
                }
            }
        }
        methodName
    }
```